# Unpivot monthly plan data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

How can I transform this input

```
Product | CC | 2017_11 | 2017_12
Product X | 220 | 100 | 200
```

into something like this?

```
Product | CC | Month |EUR
Product X | 220 | 2017_11 | 100
Product X | 220 | 2017_12 | 200
```

I tried it with UNPIVOT but was not able to get the period headers into rows.
Here is my sample

```
    SELECT Product, [month] FROM 

(SELECT Product
            [2017_11],
            [2017_12]
 FROM
[MONTHLY_REPORTING].[dbo].[FP_2017_2018_V2_revenue_import]

)
as input

UNPIVOT 
    ([month] FOR month_x IN ([2017_11], [2017_12])) as U1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpivot table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758091/unpivot-table-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `UNPIVOT` the value, in your case `EUR`, for `month` in your headers

```
 SELECT Product, [month], [EUR] 
FROM (
    SELECT
        Product
        ,[2017_11]
        ,[2017_12]
     FROM [MONTHLY_REPORTING].[dbo].[FP_2017_2018_V2_revenue_import]
) as input
UNPIVOT (
    [EUR] FOR [month] IN ([2017_11], [2017_12])
) as U1
```

Comment: Thanks, but it tells me incorrect syntax near '(' at "Max([EUR]). The datatype for the 2017_11 and 2017_12 columns is float.

Comment: Awesome. That works with one minor issue. Doing it like this leaves out rows where the [EUR] value is NULL. Is it also possible to still show these rows with a 0 value instead of NULL? Why does UNPIVOT get rid of them?

Comment: I could do something like this `UPDATE [MONTHLY_REPORTING].[dbo].[FP_2017_2018_V2_revenue_import] Set [2017_10] = 0 where [2017_10] IS NULL`
 but that does not look too elegant

Comment: you could check with `ISNULL() ` in your subquery, eg. `ISNULL([2017_11],0) AS [2017_11]` for all columns that have NULLs